# What's the timestamp format in a rails cache entry in redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

When I look at a rails cache key in redis, it looks like this:

```
 get cache:pause_mything
"\x04\bo: ActiveSupport::Cache::Entry\t:\x0b@valueT:\r@version0:\x10@created_atf\x171598381810.4477415:\x10@expires_in0"
```

How do I interpret that "created_at" timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is [Marshalled](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Marshal.html). You can deserialize with ruby like so:

```
Marshal.load("\x04\bo: ActiveSupport::Cache::Entry\t:\x0b@valueT:\r@version0:\x10@created_atf\x171598381810.4477415:\x10@expires_in0")
# => #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Entry:0x000055904baf7ae0 @value=true, @version=nil, @created_at=1598381810.4477415, @expires_in=nil>
```

This reveals that the actual value of your created_at field is `1598381810.4477415`. This is just a unix timestamp, seconds since 01.01.1970. Turn it back into a `Time` using `.at`

```
Time.at(1598381810.4477415) # => 2020-08-25 18:56:50 +0000
```